# extracting strings from KML file

Tags: android, kml

I am extracting strings from KML file, if the string contains special character like !, @, #, ', " etc. its using codes like `&#39;`

I am not able to extract entire string if it is like above, by calling getNodeValue(). It is terminating the string at special character.

```
<name>Continue onto Royal&#39;s Market</name>
```

If i extract the string i am getting only ""Continue onto Royal". I want entire string as
Continue onto Royal's Market.

How to achieve this ?? If anybody familiar with this please reply to this one.

Thanks

Comment: Might help if you post a snippet of the XML for the KML File that is causing the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem has nothing to do with KML but is general for XML parsning:

Don't use getNodeValue(), as there is no guarantee in DOM that text isn't actually split over several nodes.

Try using getTextContent() instead.

You might also have to replace entities, as in:  node.getTextContent().replaceAll("&#39;","'");

In general I wouldnt use DOM at all for extracting data. 
I'd use the XmlPullParser as its simpler to work with - and parses faster.

Comment: **Mr. Jacob Nordfalk** the function **replaeAll()** is working with **"&#160;"** but not with **"&#39;"**. Why i don't know. Just now i checked. Any how thanks a lot for your help.